# get_object significantly more slow than wget

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 server that exchanges frequently files with an S3 bucket and I'm using the AWS PHP SDK (version 1.6) to perform all the transactions. One way is to use the [get_object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonS3/get_object) method as follows:

```
$response = $s3->get_object($bucket, 'large_video.mov', array(
    'fileDownload' => 'large_video.mov'
));
```

This method is extremely slow! To download to the EC2 server a 2GB file it takes more than 20 minues. An alternative is to use the linux `wget` command which is very fast (about 40MB/sec)!

I cannot find any documentation on why get_object is so slow, are there any additional actions performed using get_object or I use it wrongly? Both the bucket and the instance are in the same area. I would appreciate some insights on why `get_object` is so much slower than `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

get_object() just passes the request to cURL's PHP bindings, which then hits the S3 API, which then returns the binary data. That's pretty much it. Nothing magical happening.

The only thing I can think of is that you haven't set the endpoint in the SDK to point to the region that the object is in. It would be worth a shot, anyway.